# Android: How to create triangle layout for ticket?

Tags: android, android-view

[image: How to create this kind of ticket design?]

I need to implement a layout similar to the above image

**My Implementation**

1. Created a triangle shape in XML (shape_triangle.xml).
2. In a horizontal linear layout added multiple image views with src as "shape_triangle"

**Question:** Is there any better approach for this?

In my XML i have to add multiple image views inside horizontal linear layout. So instead of adding multiple image views can I do something better?

**My Code Implementation**

**shape_triangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="#c6802a" />
                <solid android:color="#c6802a" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**my_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="180"
                        android:src="@drawable/pass_shape_triangle" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just use a 9-patch image as background . Creating it with drawable is tricky . You can create a Custom View which is also tricky [Reference](https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView). So better to use a 9-patch image as background .

Comment: make vector asset from your png file and use that as background